# How to make Bluetooth to stop search for devices?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have a sound bar which can be connected through Bluetooth. And my laptop has a Bluetooth adapter.
I am using Windows 10 Pro as operating system.

I have paired and successfully connected to the device. However, my PC is always searching for devices. I don't want my PC to search for any other device. Can I somehow make this stop?

Comment: Forreals. Seems like a serious potential security hole.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution, this works tested on multiple computers.

1. Go in search bar and type: Administrative Tools and click it
2. Click Services
3. Scroll down and go to Bluetooth Support Services and stop it

It will still show like it's searching but it's not in fact, you can try to pair another device or attach to the bluetooth and it will not work. Also the only thing that the bluetooth will be connect it to, it's the devices you have connected prior to disabling searching, and they work.

As well, try to click the properties of both bluetooth options, and set to "manual" so it will not run at start-up.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this, but not with the Bluetooth settings in System Settings. Even with Discovery deselected, the search went on.

I was apparently successful when I went into the `Services` applet and stopped the service: `Bluetooth Support Service`. No more unpaired devices listed! That service is set to start Manually (Triggered). Since it is Manual, it won't restart at startup.

Here's the catch: With that service stopped, the `More Bluetooth Options` applet won't even start. This is easily overcome by manually starting the service from the `Services` applet, though. So you just need to remember to start the service if you want to pair a new device.

Comment: Not sure if this service was changed recently, but stopping this service stops Bluetooth from working entirely. The description even reads "Stopping or disabling this service may cause already installed Bluetooth devices to fail to operate properly..."

Answer (score 1):

Please keep your service in manual mode as described above. The computer scans for Bluetooth devices only when you click "add Bluetooth devices" if the settings is in "Manual" mode. It does not search for devices when you come out of settings. It works only when you right click the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Settings and click the Bluetooth tab, scroll down to the ‘Related Settings’ and click ‘More Bluetooth options’. In the very first tab ‘Options’ you will see a ‘Discovery’ section with an ‘Allow Bluetooth devices to find this PC’ option. Uncheck the option, and click the ‘Apply’ button at the bottom.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't seem like it stops scanning.

Comment: This answer does indeed not solve the problem. The Bluetooth module is still scanning for devices, which is apparent by the list of unpaired devices that is still updated. Being discoverable and discover others is not the same thing; furthermore discovering Bluetooth devices is quite an energy-consuming process. So it would be nice to have an option to disable scanning.