# Windows 10: Set Bluetooth visibility via Group Policy

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, group-policy

Is there a way to enable the bluetooth adapter in windows 10 but disable device discovery? In the bluetooth settings there is a checkbox "Allow Bluetooth devices to find this PC". Im looking for a way to set this up via Group Policy.

I cannot believe, this is an unusual task, but I cannot find a setting for it.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This is a similar question: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1064031/how-to-make-bluetooth-to-stop-search-for-devices)